# How to load multiple images with the same CRS?

Tags: qgis, image

When I add several images to QGIS 1.8 it asks the coordinate reference system for each one. There are several seconds in between the dialog and it is not easy to just continue working as the dialog keeps popping up with focus.

Is there any way to check "the same" CRS for all selected (inserted) rasters?
With 10 it is not that big of a deal but when it is 100 it seems to occupy a lot of time.

I normally use the gui so writing a batch program is not what I am looking for.
I select NOT all of the images in a given folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under'Options', choose the 'CRS' tab, and see the choices for new layers. Choose either "Use project CRS", or 'Use default CRS displayed below'.

Comment: too cool. that saves a bunch of time.